# Why is change function not firing on radio input in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, onchange

[image: Two radio inputs]

Okay, so in my code, I have these two radio inputs, one with a fixed value, one with an input-field to take the dynamic value.

Now what I wanted to do is, when the user enters value in the input field, the corresponding radio button will get selected automatically, and the values will get updated as well. and if the user selects the default value, the state will get updated with the default value.

My code looks like this..

```
<ul className='list-unstyled mb-0 d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row justify-content-around'>
                <li className='mr-4'> 
                    <input 
                        defaultChecked
                        onChange={() => updateState('timeLimit',defaultTime)}
                        type="radio" 
                        value={defaultTime}
                        name='time' 
                        className='mr-2' 
                        id="defaultTime"/>
                    <label htmlFor="defaultTime"> {defaultTime} Mins. (default)</label> 
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <input 
                        onChange={(e) => updateState('timeLimit',e.target.value)}
                        type="radio" 
                        name='time' 
                        value={customTime}
                        ref={customTimeRef}
                        className='mr-2' 
                        id="customTime"/> 
                    <label htmlFor="customTime">
                        <input 
                            onChange={(e) => updateCustomTime(e.target.value)}
                            style={{outline:'none', border:'none',width:'9rem'}} 
                            placeholder='Enter Your Time'
                            min='0' 
                            className='border-bottom border-info pl-2 pb-1' 
                            type="number"/> Mins. (custom) 
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

The functions are defined as

```
const updateCustomTime = (val) => {
    if(customTimeRef.current.checked){
        setCustomTime(val)
        updateState('timeLiimit',val)
    }
    else{
        customTimeRef.current.checked=true
        setCustomTime(val)
        updateState('timeLiimit',val)
    }
}
```

Now the issue is, when I type into my input field, the updateState function is fired, the radio gets checked, but if I click on  the radio buttons afterwards, they aren't firing the onchange events associated.

What's wrong here ? And how to achieve the desired result ??

Comment: I hope this `updateState('timeLiimit',val)` typo is not the issue

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but no, It was not the issue. the event wasn't firing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this component

> use a boolean state to set the `checked` property

```
const App = () => {
  const [useDefault, setUseDefault] = React.useState(true)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="time" checked={useDefault} onClick={() => setUseDefault(true)} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="time" checked={!useDefault} />
        <input type="text" onKeyUp={() => setUseDefault(false)} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Ahh, yes, so silly of me, I couldn't think of using a state to handle that.
 
Thanks a lot buddy, just tweaked your code a little and it's working perfectly. Thanks.